# expo init fails React-native@https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time

Tags: react-native, expo

I am following the [React Native getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started).
I installed expo-cli globaly, but

```
expo init AwesomeProject
```

fails
with the following error:

```
npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for react-native@https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz (sha512-/qr69tLChymCyNpTvBiHpepa1ufF43cCMtUzpaQxmCwG6Kz5Z9XqyoEP1lJaJ/BNFj/Bp9+l+LIHwvrDoPBnfQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

Comment: WARN only gives you a warning and doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Thanks, but the init command hangs... I have tried uninstalling expo and re-installing which didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Expo didn't work, but I was able to solve this by using npx.
I guess this is what npx is for

```
npx expo init AwesomeProject
```

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
command adb kill-server
```

before:

```
npx expo init AwesomeProject
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the terminal with "Run as Administrator".